# How do I send telemetry data via mqtt to a second component in IoT Central?

Tags: azure-iot-central

I am at a bit of a loss and need a bright idea.

I have created a new device model in IoT Central which has two components and an interface.
The interface is also in the default component.

[Device Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRFjg.png)

If I now send my data via mqtt, I do this via mqtt to the endpoint /devices//messages/events.

[mqtt request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12PVd.png)

This works so far that my telemetry data can be assigned to the properties of the default component and the interface contained there.

[raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChXAV.png)

However, I do not manage to assign data to the second component. These are always displayed as _unmodeleddata.

My question: Why is the telemetry data for the second component not matched against the data model?

Thank you for the explanation.

Best Regards
Init5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending the telemetry data must be done by component with a specific component name. Only  a default component doesn't need this name.

The following example shows how can be setup this component name in the *topic* in the case of direct MQTT protocol:

```
devices/mydevice/messages/events/$.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8&$.sub=myComponentName
```

More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-pnp/concepts-developer-guide-device?pivots=programming-language-csharp).

Comment: Thank you, Roman. That was exactly the point. Do you have a link to a corresponding documentation? Unfortunately, I haven't found anything specific on the Microsoft pages. That would be great.

Thanks Init5

Comment: have a look at the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-pnp/concepts-convention#telemetry